# How to align numbering next to table in LibreOffice?

Tags: alignment, libreoffice

I would like to have a small table centered horizontally in my document with numbering at the right edge of the page, centered vertically.  This is easy to do for images or formulas as shown here:

[image]

But with tables I can't figure out how to get them to behave nicely like a character.  I also tried putting the table in a frame which works except that the frame cuts off some of the table borders and leaves space below the table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Using a frame is the right way IMHO. To avoid cutting of frame content, you may set the `Spacing to contents` values on the `Border` tab of the frame definition accordingly. On the `Wrap` tab, you can edit the spacing below the frame.